# How to merge rows and count their column values SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table (table_x):

```
   GAME_ID   |   TEAM_ID   |   MATCH_GOALS   |   VICTORY
      1             1               1               1
      1             4               0               0
      2             6               4               1
      2             2               2               0
      3             1               3               1
      3             6               1               0
     ...           ...             ...
```

I've been trying to create a SQL query script that gives me a new table(table_y) from table_x, that merges rows that have the same TEAM_ID and SUM their MATCH_GOALS as well as their VICTORIES, like this:

```
   TEAM_ID   |   TOTAL_GOALS   |   VICTORIES
      1               4                2
      2               2                0
      4               0                0
      6               5                1
     ...             ...              ...
```

However I was unsuccessful, any help is appreciated!

Ps: I'm using PostgreSQL 9.5

Edit: Here is what I've tried

```
SELECT 
  team_id,
  COUNT(scoreboard.match_goals) AS total_goals
FROM(
  SELECT 
    team_game.game_id, 
    team_game.team_id,
    CASE
    WHEN team_id = house_team THEN house_goals
    ELSE visitor_goals
    END as match_goals
  FROM 
    public.team_game, 
    public.game
  WHERE 
    team_game.game_id = game.game_id
  ORDER BY
    game.game_id ASC) as scoreboard
GROUP BY
  team_id
ORDER BY
  team_id;
```

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Show us what you tried.  Surely there is some resource available when you google 'Postgres sum values'

Comment: Why the down vote? I just edited in what I've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select a.*, b.victories 
from 
    (select team_id, sum(match_goals) as total_goals from table_x group by team_id) as a
join 
    (select team_id, sum(victory) as victories from table_x group by team_id) as b 
on a.team_id = b.team_id
```

Comment: here you need to do each sum separately and then join them so they dont interfere with each other for the grouping.

Comment: @user3700389 do you think single select with group by team id work ?

select team_id, sum(match_goals) as total_goals, sum(victory) as victories from table_x group by team_id

Comment: @AlexandreKrabbe can you please try 'select team_id, sum(match_goals) as total_goals, sum(victory) as victories from table_x group by team_id' i just want to know. it should work

Comment: yeah maybe could work, im used to doing things separately to make sure there is no conflicts, but you may be right here